# SQL assigning incremental ID to subgroups

Tags: sql

As the title says, I'm trying to add an extra column to a table which autoincrements everytime a different string in another column changes.
I would like to do this in a query.

Example:

```
MyCol   GroupID
Cable   1
Cable   1
Foo     2
Foo     2
Foo     2
Fuzz    3
Fizz    4
Tv      5
Tv      5
```

The GroupID column is what I want to accomplish.

We can be sure that MyCol's strings will be the same in each subgroup (Foo will always be Foo, etc).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by col1) as groupid
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a temporal table with the distinct value of the MyCol and get the groupId throught the RowNumber of the temp table, and join the rownumbered result with your table.

This is a raw example in oracle:

```
WITH data AS
  (SELECT 'Cable' MyCol FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Cable' FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Foo' FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Foo' FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Foo' FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Fuzz' FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Fizz' FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Tv' FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Tv' FROM dual
  ),
  tablename AS
  (SELECT * FROM data
  ),
  temp AS
  ( SELECT DISTINCT mycol FROM tablename
  ),
  temp2 AS
  ( SELECT mycol, rownum AS groupid from temp
  )
SELECT tablename.mycol, temp2.groupid FROM temp2 JOIN tablename ON temp2.mycol = tablename.mycol
```

You could also check for a way to implement the [tabibitosan](http://rwijk.blogspot.com.co/2014/01/tabibitosan.html) method knowing that your column condition is string.